# bash script not being run by cron

Tags: linux, debian, shell-script, cron

I have a very simple bash script that runs flawlessly when I do

```
./removeOldBackup.sh
```

or

```
sh /home/myusername/backup/removeOldBackup.sh
```

but when I add it to crontab like

```
* * * * * sh /home/myusername/backup/removeOldBackup.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/myusername/backup/removeOldBackup.sh
```

it never works...

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name 'files_20[1-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[1-2][1-9]--*' -delete
find . -name 'files_20[1-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-0[2-9]--*' -delete

find . -name 'database_20[1-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[1-2][1-9]--*' -delete
find . -name 'database_20[1-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-0[2-9]--*' -delete
```

This is my script permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 295 Jul 25 10:07 /home/myusername/backup/removeOldBackup.sh
```

Crontab is added for user root.

This is what I find in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 25 10:11:01 myservername /USR/SBIN/CRON[7583]: (root) CMD (sh /home/myusername/backup/removeOldBackup.sh)
```

So again, when I run the script manually, my backup files get removed correctly. When it is run by cron, they never get removed. I'm using debian-6.0-x86_64.

Comment: Your `find` runs on current working directory ie. when you run your script as `./script.sh`, everything works fine. However, when cron runs your script, the current working directory is not what you expect it to be. Add `cd /correct/path` in the beginning of your script or use an absolute path for `find`.

Comment: I tried to find an answer here on stackexchange as well as googling but didn't think the path might be the reason. I just thought  the script doesn't run at all. Thank you both for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalise and expand on what someone said in a comment, when you put something in root's crontab it will run inside `/root`, not in the directory the script is in, because `cron` doesn't even know where that is. Because your backup files aren't in that directory tree, the `find` command never reaches them. So the job is running, it just never finds any files to delete. Providing an absolute path to `find` or adding `cd /home/myusername/backup` first will fix your problem.

Nonetheless, there doesn't seem to be a need to run this cronjob as root at all: all the files are inside `myusername`'s home directory and presumably owned by them too. Why not put your cronjob inside that user's crontab instead? Run `crontab -e` as `myusername` and add the exact same line you used for root's version. That way you aren't needlessly running a task as a privileged user (which automatically deletes files, no less), and you'll also be in a working location for the script to start with.

Comment: Backup files are generated by root. I know it might not be the best practice, but I don't have time to reorganize it all now. Thank you!